# What percentile of investors in the stock market do I find myself in?

Tags: stocks, mutual-funds

What percentile of investors in the stock market do I find myself in?

Via luck and/or skill over the past 16-years I beat the S&P 500 12/16 years.  If I invested in the S&P 500 over the last 16-years, then I would have ~$1.00, but I have ~$2.19.  I averaged a 13.65% return.  I cannot figure out how good this is.  What percentile of investors am I in?

Where can I find this type of information?  I have searched Google quite a bit.  Searching Google has not been kind to me.  lots of noise with the search term percentile.  Lots of results about not trying to beat the market (I invest in the things politicians talk about on the news).  Lots of articles on mutual fund managers not beating the market.  Nothing about how investors perform by percentile.

---

Edit: I don't understand the down-vote.  Is this not the correct forum?

---

Edit:

Well I found this about the German stock market from 2000-2007.  The yearly mean investor in the 95% had a 7.66% yearly return.  The yearly mean investor in the 99% had a 17.20% yearly return.  So maybe somewhere in that range?

https://books.google.com/books?id=0gR4DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA30&lpg=PA30&dq=investor+performance+percentile&source=bl&ots=I6hyIaJELj&sig=ACfU3U3U5VhYnRGwwDdRtVLGUHg5ejBCBw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-3_LryL3nAhVNWq0KHdrPBIQQ6AEwBXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=investor%20performance%20percentile&f=false

There must be similar studies done in America.

Comment: You're not going to find any source of information that provides  statistics of individual  investor returns.  The only  thing that you can do is determine your performance versus the benchmark indexes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Do you have a particular practical reason for asking, or are you asking out of curiosity? If you really want to know if you're better than the market, you'll need a more powerful technique than just looking at your win rate and lifetime returns. Something like a paired-sample *t*-test.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume the market is [perfectly efficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficient-market_hypothesis) such that any investor has a 50% chance of beating the S&P 500 in a particular year. Given that assumption, what would be the probability of somebody beating the market at least 12/16 years, purely by random chance? This is a simple binomial distribution. You can do the math or use a calculator online to find that the probability is ~4%. So I would say you are in the 96th percentile of investors. Not bad but not enough evidence to quit your day job, in my opinion. Comparing your actual returns to the market or other investors would take more data.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a plethora of articles on the median or mean investor.  If there is data for a median or mean investor, then there would also be data across the spectrum.

Now we can say that such studies are not reality, but we can also use them to model reality.  They must certainly be a thing.

---

I invest in a sector based mainly on politics (whatever the politicians are talking about).  I think that investing in individual companies is not for me.

I was able to find around about what/when I was invested in my 401(k) [I have another 401(k), and my wife in is charge of some other investments].  I started with ~$14.00 (I cut off some zeroes) in 2004 and ended up with ~$110.00 at the end of  2019.

December 2003 $14.00
FSDIX / 2004 / 14.72% / $16.06 / S&P 500 08.99%

FSDIX / 2005 / 09.79% / $17.63 / S&P 500 03.00%

FSDIX / 2006 / 13.96% / $20.09 / S&P 500 13.62%

FSDIX / 2007 / 07.43% / $21.59 / S&P 500 03.53%

FSDIX / 2008 /-41.17% / $12.70 / S&P 500 -38.49%

FXMEX / 2009 / 32.63% / $16.84 / S&P 500 23.45%

FXMEX / 2010 / 21.71% / $20.50 / S&P 500 12.78%

FXMEX / 2011 / -3.42% / $19.80 / S&P 500 00000%

FXMEX / 2012 / 15.62% / $22.89 / S&P 500 13.41%

FXMEX / 2013 / 41.30% / $32.35 / S&P 500 29.60%

FXMEX / 2014 / 26.70% / $40.98 / S&P 500 11.39%

FXMEX / 2015 / 07.11% / $43.90 / S&P 500 -0.73%

FXMEX / 2016 / 08.68% / $47.71 / S&P 500 09.54%

FSDAX / 2017 / 34.21% / $64.03 / S&P 500 19.42%

FSDAX / 2018 / -6.74% / $59.71 / S&P 500 -6.24%

FSDAX / 2019 / 33.74% / $79.86 / S&P 500 31.50%

So there is another ~$30.14 in there someplace based on luck and/or skill from timing.